# Insert value in a web view

Tags: android, input, android-webview

There have been lot of posts to how to insert value in a web view but there has been lot of confusion regarding the syntax. Here is a simple scenario - there is a list of username and passwords and when the user select one of the username the username and password should be inserted in the input boxes of the webpage. The web page used is facebook.com. Here is the code for web view part. This codes activates when the username is selected from the list view -

```
WebView wb;
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wb.loadUrl(url);
LoginActivity.this.wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wb, String url) {
    wb.loadUrl(url);
    //System.out.println("url activated 1");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView wb, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("page loading finished 1");
    wb.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('email').value = '"+uname+"';document.getElementById('pass').value='"+pass+"';");
}
});
```

I still don't know weather the syntax to input the value in the webview is correct on not. The above code is not working. Kindly help!

UPDATED QUESTION -

There are two name tags in the link - "https://m.facebook.com/login/" as "email" and "name". I want to enter the email and password from a edittext boxes as ed2 and ed3 to the web view (wb) on the click of button b2. I used the following code -

```
 b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            uname = ed2.getText().toString();
            pass = ed3.getText().toString();

            wb.loadUrl(url);
            wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wb, String url) {
                    wb.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView wb, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    wb.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementByTagName('email').value='" + uname
                            + "';document.getElementByTagName('pass').value='" + pass + "';})()");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

but it showing two errors -

09-15 11:59:43.555: W/BindingManager(26200): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 26200

09-15 11:59:43.890: I/chromium(26200): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByTagName is not a function", source:  (1)

clearly there is some problem with the syntax. Kindly help!

Comment: still there is no clarity in the syntax. 
The error was - "attempt to finish the input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed"

Comment: @ArpitKumar check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried

```
getElementsByName('login')[0].submit();
```

but it doesn't work. I try to submit the form Its working fine.

```
  document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

javascript is like

```
 "javascript:(
             function()
             {
                document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='"+uname+"';
                document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='"+pass+"';
                document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
             })()"
```

Here is the code

```
 ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        uname = ed2.getText().toString();
        pass = ed3.getText().toString();

        WebView wb;
        wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wb.loadUrl(url);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String uname = "email@mail.com";
            //String pass = "******";               
            web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='"
                    + uname
                    + "';document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='"
                    + pass + "';document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();})()");
        }
    });
 }
 });
```

Comment: Hello arun, I tried the code but it is not working. Let me change the question a bit.

Comment: Thankyou so much arun. It would be great if you can add the syntax to click the button

Comment: Hey arun, the button i mentioned earlier belongs to the button in facebook page ie the login button.

Comment: U mean Using Facebook SDK

Comment: Nope. The button which you can view in the webview. How can we call the click event on the button using javascript.

Comment: @arun..thank you so much..:)..can you please recommend some book/online tutorial to learn all this?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView wb;
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wb.loadUrl(url);
LoginActivity.this.wb.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wb, String url) {
wb.loadUrl(url);
//System.out.println("url activated 1");
return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView wb, String url) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//System.out.println("page loading finished 1");
wb.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('email').value ='"+uname+"';document.getElementById('pass').value='"+pass+"';");
}
});
```

Please check that i have made change to the setWebViewClient method. So now include your own class which extends WebViewClient such like below.

```
public class OurViewClient extends WebViewClient {

public boolean shouldOverride(WebView v,String url){
    v.loadUrl(url);
    return true;

}
```

Comment: The question is - What is the syntax to insert a value in the input box of a webview? Can you be precise on the answer? Thanx

Comment: input box? you mean the address bar or any other input box in the website

Comment: Input box where user can type a value. In the above link i.e. facebook.com, there are two input boxes one for email and the other for password.